# Install Sonic 3 & Knuckles Separately

Tags: steam, sonic-3-and-knuckles

I don't think I have an adequate title for this issue but oh well...

[Sonic 3 A.I.R.](http://sonic3air.org/) is now available and, according to the site, I have to install the Steam version of Sonic 3 & Knuckles (for game files). However, I own it as part of the SEGA Mega Drive and Genesis Classics bundle, I don't own it individually. Steam doesn't give me the option to download it as an individual game. Clicking Play on the site launches the game through SMD&GC, not as an individual game. How do I do that so I can play A.I.R.?

Comment: have you attempted to download and play AIR yet? based on how most bundles work, you should in theory be able to play the game since you already have the game files for S3&K on your PC.

Comment: I have. The SEGA logo is cut off on the bottom and most of the title screen and many assets in the game are missing.

Comment: try to contact SEGA and Blit Software both respectively on this. a little more looking in says that this is a **package**, not a **bundle**. a bundle is buying all games in one fell swoop while owning them separately, while a package is buying one game that has many included as features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue. Silly me didn't look in the manual that came with AIR.

Here is what I did:

1. Navigate to the AIR directory: `%appdata%\Sonic3AIR`
2. Open `settings.json`
3. Change `"UseSoftwareRenderer" : false` to `true`

After that it ran without any issues.